# Check whether or not my system supports network booting

Tags: networking, remote-installation

How do I check whether my system supports network booting?

I don't see an ethernet option in my boot priority list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not necessarily see the name of your network adapter in the boot priority list. You may see "Network Adapter" or "PXE Boot" instead.

To get an exact answer I would consult the manual for your motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake. There LAN option was disabled in another section. Now it is working.

On one machine I enabled `LAN Option ROM` under Advanced > Onboard Devices Configuration. On another, a similar option was available under a menu item named Northbridge (or was it South bridge? not sure).

Comment: Thanks for updating us to let us know that your problem was solved! If you would like to update your answer to tell us what information you found, you could help make this post informative for future visitors who may find it.

Comment: Sure. I've updated my post :)